# How to use SSR in nextjs 14 + react-query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query

I did everything according to the documentation, but there is no server rendering

I have created a page 
`app/layout.tsx`

```
export default async function RootLayout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient()
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient)

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
          <Providers>
            <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>
               {children}
            </HydrationBoundary>
          </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

`Providers`

```
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'

function Providers({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const [client] = useState(
    new QueryClient({ defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 60 * 1000 } } })
  )

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
       {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default Providers
```

`Page`

```
export default async function AdminUsersList() {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient()
  await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['users'],
    queryFn: () => fetchUsers(0),
    initialPageParam: 0
  })

  return (
    <UserList />
  )
}
```

`userlist`

```
export default function UserList() {
  const {
    data: users,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useUsers()

  if (isLoading && !users) return <>loading...</>;

  return (
     <div>
      {!isLoading && users && (
        <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={0}
          hasMore={!isError && hasNextPage}
          loader={<Preloader key='loader' />}
          loadMore={() => fetchNextPage({ cancelRefetch: false })}
        >
            <div>
              {users.pages.map((group, i) => (
                <React.Fragment key={i}>
                  {group.users.map((user) => (
                    {user.username}
                  ))}
                </React.Fragment>
              ))}
           </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

`getQueryClient`

```
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query"

const getQueryClient = () => new QueryClient()
export default getQueryClient
```

`fetchUsers`

```
import { Error } from '@/types/error'
import { User } from '@/types/entities/user'
import { useInfiniteQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'

interface Response {
  users: User[],
  nextCursor: number
}

export async function fetchUsers(pageParam: unknown) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/admin/users?skip=${!pageParam ? 0 : pageParam}`, { cache: 'no-store' });
    return await res.json()
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw err.response.data
  }
}

export default function useUsers() {
  return useInfiniteQuery<Response, Error>({
    queryKey: ['users'],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam }) => fetchUsers(pageParam),
    initialPageParam: 0,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.nextCursor,
  })
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that. What should be done in each page like this

```
export default async function AdminUsersList() {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient()
  await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['users'],
    queryFn: () => fetchUsers(0),
    initialPageParam: 0
  })

  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}> // This
      <UserList />
    </HydrationBoundary>
  )
}
```

I just can't figure out why it doesn't pick it up from layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly correct. But I have a few suggestions,

Wrap you components that rely on React Query data with Suspense and HydrationBoundary. Here is a sample code:

```
import { Suspense } from 'react-query';
import { HydrationBoundary } from 'react- 
query/hydration';

function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();
  const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <HydrationBoundary state={dehydratedState}>
              {children}
            </HydrationBoundary>
          </Suspense>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same